# MVC 5 data annotation validation compare attribute for password field does not work client side

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

The validation message should be displayed when user has entered not equal confirm password and navigated to another field.

Comment: The client-side functionality is provided by the jQuery Validation Plugin. That means 1) it could be a bug in that plugin or 2) JavaScript errors or conflicting scripts could be at play. You'll need to do some basic debugging yourself and come back and update your question with results.

Comment: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") i referenced both this file & for all other fields client validation working fine except for passwordfor @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 
[DataType.Password] from Model property of password field and then data-annotation client validation works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you have to add validation summury in your form as

@using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "Action", FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "XYZ", @role = "form"}))
    {

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

}